# Why does facebook add id="pageTitle" into page title on every their page?

Tags: javascript, html, title

I always knew that we need id attribute to add to an element just to have some unique access to it.
Title is suposed to be only one element in the html document, so it's a priory an unique element.

Is it something related to javascript and Frames? or because we have also attributes title and again for some javascript function would be easier to find it by ID?

thanks.

Comment: Could it be for optimization purposes? Maybe in their tests they found out that `$('#pageTitle')` is faster than `$('title')`?

Comment: Hm.. could be a reason.. at first I thought more that some injected frames(that they heavily use) might have own page titles.. and to distinguish them they have added that IDs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is two-fold:

1. Accessing anything by tag name (document.getElementsByTagName) is ALWAYS going to be slower than accessing something by id (document.getElementById). This is because getElementByTagName always returns a LIVE nodeList (or HTMLCollection). This means not only does it have to search through the entire document structure to find all the titles (and return an collection of titles), it will keep the list live and updated incase of insertion. Whereas, most browsers have a very fast method of indexing ids and it will return only the element reference (i.e. will not have to keep anything updated).
2. If you have frames on the page, then document.getElementsByTagName('title') will return a list of all the titles on the page (i.e. including any iframe titles), which is clearly not what they want. They would then have to search through the nodeList to find the title they are looking for. I did a quick example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9QtZu/:

   ```
   var titles = document.getElementsByTagName('title');
   console.log(titles);
   ```

So, using document.getElementById allows them to more quickly access main title that they are after, whilst also boosting performance. No contest.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName

Comment: Fair enough CalM. Thank you